# How to properly deploy vue 3 vite project on digitalcean app platform

Tags: vuejs3, digital-ocean, vite, digital-ocean-apps

I have deployed a vue 3 vite project on digitalocean app platform. The build process completes with no error but deployment fails with the error below
[image]

From the delploy logs, I see that the app is being served on port 5050
[image]

But both my run command `npm run preview --port 8080` and app `HTTP` port is also set to `8080`
[image]

Why is the app being served on port `5050` instead of using `8080`?